# Is there an upper bound on the number of representations as a sum of squares?

Tags: asymptotics, sums-of-squares, upper-bounds

I am interested in finding upper bounds for the [Sum of squares function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_function) defined as $r_k(n) = |\{(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k) \in \mathbb{Z}^k \ : \ n = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots + a_k^2\}|$ whenever the natural number $n$ grows to infinity.

For $k=2$ it can be found using the explicit expression of $r_2(n)$ that $r_2(n)\leq 4 o(n^\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon >0$.

For $k>4$ the work by Hardy and Mordell using the circle method give the bound $r_k(n)\leq C\cdot n^{k/2-1+\epsilon}$, for all $\epsilon>0$. (See e.g. [the introduction of this paper](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/2012/0019/0002/MRL-2012-0019-0002-a008.pdf)).

For $k=4$ there are exact formulas in terms of the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) which I think can lead to upper bound easily (but could find a reference).

Finally, for $k=3$ it is known that for squarefree $n$, $r_3(n)\leq C\cdot n^{1/2+\epsilon}$. Is this bound also true for general $n$? Is there another weaker bound for non-squarefree $n$?

I am far from being an expert in this field so I do have a lot of questions: are the bounds I have collected here correct? Are there better assymptotic bounds which I don't know? Bounds that works not for all $n$ but only asymptotically, would also be interesting. I would also appreciate a good reference for this kind of results.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: It would seem that if you already know $r_2(n) = O(n^{\epsilon})$, then the bound $r_3(n) = O(n^{1/2+\epsilon})$ follows by expressing $r_3(n) = \sum_{w} r_2(n-w^2)$ and noting that only $w$ with $|w| \le n^{1/2}$ are relevant.

Answer (score 11):

It is known since Gauss that
$$r_3(n)=12\dfrac{h(D)}{w(D)/2}(1-(D/2))\sum_{d\mid f}\mu(d)(D/d)\sigma(f/d)\;,$$
where $-n=D(2^vf)^2$, $D$ a fundamental discriminant, $v\ge-1$, $h(D)$ is the class number of $Q(\sqrt{D})$, $w(D)$ its number of roots of unity ($2$ for $D<-4$), $(D/d)$ is the Kronecker--Legendre symbol, and $\sigma$ the sum of divisors function. It is known that $h(D)=O(|D|^{1/2})$ and $\sigma(f)=O(f^{1+\epsilon})$, so indeed the bound is true for all $n$.

Comment: Great! Thank you a lot. Could you also help me with the other questions?

Comment: There are explicit formulas for $r_k(n)$ for $k=2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ and $k=10$. For general $k$, the function $\theta^k$ is an explicit factor times an Eisenstein series of weight $k/2$ plus a cusp form, and the Eisenstein series term dominate. I don't have time to elaborate.